# splitting one image into sub-images and more

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have X images, each is MxN pixels size. I want to split each image into Y sub-images and sum the pixels' values in each sub-image. The sub-image with the highest sum will be inserted to a new array. Can someone guide me how to begin this task? (I've already loaded the TIFF file with all the images).

Comment: The functions `conv2` or `blockproc` may help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Split Images into parts using MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514251/how-to-split-images-into-parts-using-matlab)

Comment: 10x, I found both of comments helpful.